# wp-load.php & require_once, in an ajax call

Tags: ajax, wordpress, require-once

I am developing a WP Plugin.

Currently, I am making an ajax call with jquery to a standalone php file in my plugin folder.
Let's presume that this file is called **test.php**.

The file is NOT loaded prior to this call, so no native wordpress functions work in this file.

As a result, I have `require_once('wp.load');` in test.php.

Here stems my questions:

1. The only function I need from wordpress is $wpdb->insert.  Is there a better function to include than wp-load?  Something that doesn't include so much, since all I need is this one function!
2. I understand that require_once loads the file, ONLY if it hasn't been loaded yet.  Maybe I'm overlooking the situation, but how does this work with ajax?  If there is a "success" response, does test.php close, thus when its called again, it loads `wp-load.php` again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If there is a "success" response, does test.php close, thus when its
>   called again, it loads wp-load.php again?

Exactly. The concept behind [`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) (or [`include_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)) is to make sure you don’t reload the same functions, classes & variables into the same *currently running* PHP code at the same time:

> `include_once` may be used in cases where the same file might be
>   included and evaluated more than once during a particular execution of
>   a script, so in this case it may help avoid problems such as function
>   redefinitions, variable value reassignments, etc.

And since PHP scripts run only on request, what you describe is exactly how it would happen.

That said, I wouldn’t over-think the concept of loading the whole `wp.load` each time it’s needed. I doubt it will cause such a performance hit that it would even be noticeable.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your response (I think, due to my poor wording).  So does using require_once actually make a difference when using AJAX to ref. side server file?  Or does it not make a difference if I use require vs require_once?

Comment: Ahh, got it.  I'm not worried about errors, I was just curious.  Essentially, I just want to optimize this as much as possible, and it seems like the way I have should be fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider follow [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) method to write an Ajax powered plugin. There is usualy no need to create a separate PHP file and load WordPress core into that file. Read that carefully and you'll find out, that is relatively easy to accomplish and is more flexible thant stand alone PHP file...

Comment: The problem is it's not a personal ajax plugin but actually [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com/), which is much too complex to rebuild as such.